# Mockito wait for method from new thread to executes a number of times

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, mockito, azureservicebus

So I have the following things: a spring boot application that starts by listening to messages from a queue and processes them and some UTs and ITs for it. Now, from an integration test class, I want to verify that if I post a big number of messages to the input queue, my application won't crash.

For posting, from this method test, I'm connection to queue and post some dummy messages, than I start a new thread using `Mockito#spy`. So far so good as other IT exists for just one message. Than I'm using an `ArgumentCaptor` to see that the message that I sent to queue was successfully processes by my application thread.

What I don't know how to do is to wait for the execution of thousands of the processing method calls to see that the application won't crash. The test should end with no exception thrown after all the messages were read from queue (I'm not validating the messages as for now it's not required). The time of processing should be between 1 and 2 hours.

I've read about `CountDownLatch` but can't figure out how to wait for the thread to execute as long as it needs to process all my messages, if that is indeed an aid to use.

Can anyone suggest an implementation design for what I'm trying to do here? Or is there any chance that what I'm trying to do is not possible?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
I cannot modify the tested application method or class, so is there a way to retrieve the number of calls to my method?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Awaitility](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility). In this particular case, the test case should start message processing asynchronously and then use Awaitility to await for condition.

This one will wait forever until condition is satisfied.

```
Awaitility.await().forever().until(conditionIsSatisfied());
```

Alternatively you could specify min and/or max time to wait:

```
Awaitility.await().atLeast(1, HOURS).and().atMost(2, HOURS).until(conditionIsSatisfied());
```

Where `conditionIsSatisfied` is callable capable to check if some expected number of messages has been already processed:

```
private Callable<Boolean> conditionIsSatisfied() {
      return new Callable<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean call() throws Exception {
                  return allMessagesProcessed;
            }
      };
}
```

See [usage](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility/wiki/Usage#usage-examples) page for more examples.

Comment: Very good answer, but in my case I cannot see a way to retrieve the number of processed messages from the application that I'm testing without to modify the tested application. The reason why I cannot modify it is that is a production code and it's not allowed to do that just for a test. I'll update the question

Comment: @bogdan.rusu Unfortunately, it is hard to propose something more concrete and meaningful without code samples provided.